# Could not load file or assembly is Visual Studio 2013 but not 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the classic "Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXX' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." when debugging my application from Visual Studio 2013.

I have spent hours adjusting the platform targets, removing references, etc. Sometimes the XXXXX is a referenced DLL sometimes it is my own assembly. Everything is targeted framework 4.0.

The strange part is that when I load the solution with 2010 I do not get the same error. What's different between the two as far as debugging Asp.net?

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" sounds like an X86 vs X64 issue.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but I've adjusted the platform targets to my wits ends. And I don't get the same error under VS2010.

Comment: What's surprising is that when I set platform to Any the XXXXX assembly is a referenced DLL (probably 32bit). And when I set my application to x86 the XXXXX cited is my assembly.